# Errors in the data received through serial using Python

Tags: python, pyserial

I want to send data to a peripheral using PySerial. However, errors *sometime* appear in the data received.

```
import serial

dongle = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 9600)

dongle.write("Some data\n")
```

And then, `Some data\n` is transmitted to the peripheral.

Sometime it works great, but sometime, errors appear in the data received: `Somata\n`, `Som a\n`, etc…

How to fix that issue?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to add an inter-char delay to your serial write. Unfortunately, such a thing is not available in PySerial. There is an `inter_byte_timeout`, but that's for reads.

Something like:

```
import serial
import time

def write_with_delay(command):
    while len(command)>0: # Loop till all of string has been sent
        char_to_tx = command[0] # Get a
        dongle.write(char_to_tx)
        command = command[1:] # Remove sent character                                
        time.sleep(0.01)

dongle = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 9600)
write_with_delay('Some data\n')
```

Which will send the string with a 10ms (0.01s) delay between each character. Ordinarily, adding arbitrary delays into code is a bad thing, but for serial comms it is sometimes necessary.